# PHP - It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I have just activated/installed PHP and mySQL on my Mac and all seemed to be going well until I accessed a table which used dates.

On the live server - where I was previously developing the site - exactly the same page worked fine.

On my local site I get the following messages for each row in the table:

`Warning: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/London' for 'BST/1.0/DST' instead in /Users/mysite/Sites/testsite/index.php on line 26`

`Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/London' for 'BST/1.0/DST' instead in /Users/mysite/Sites/testsite/index.php on line 26`

Any ideas how to stop this. I'm guessing I need to change a setting somewhere.

Comment: I'm guessing the only thing you need is read the error message, not just copy/paste it on stackoverflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765158/date-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings-in-codeigniter)

Comment: ***Note:*** The `php-cli`'s `php.ini` file is different then `apache2`'s `php.ini` file. I suggest symbolic linking one to another to keep them in sync and avoid confusion!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Any ideas how to stop this.

The error message tells you how to stop this.

> You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.

Update your PHP installation's `php.ini` (likely `/etc/php.ini`) file to have a `date.timezone` setting, or use `date_default_timezone_set()` in your scripts.

You're only now seeing this because it starts happening in PHP 5.3+.

Comment: More specifically, prior to 5.3 it was a _notice_; now it is a _warning_.