# how to get timezone information

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, localization, timezone

i have a login script in that i check if a certain timeperiod has passed or not. to realize that i have a timestamp that i fetch with strtotime from my db so that i easily can add to this time/string a value of seconds to check if this specific date/time has passed.

yesterday i updated to php 5.3. now i get an error message:

```
Warning: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead in /xxx/xxx/xxxx/xxx/login.php on line xx
```

which realates on this line:

```
$DOA = strtotime($row->DOA);
```

the question is, how can i use:

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin"
date.default_latitude = 52.5194
date.default_longitude = 13.4067
```

to convert the timestamp

```
$row->DOA
```

that i have to get as a string. or is this:

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin"
date.default_latitude = 52.5194
date.default_longitude = 13.4067
```

just an information that i should add  because it is said that

```
We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead...
```

is used.

if there is somebody who could give me advise to solve this i really would appreciate.

Comment: The question title does not match the question itself and even the question alone is pretty confusing. Do you want to obtain the client's time zone? Do you want to find out your time zone? Do you need help to fix the warning? Do you want to convert between time zones?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032660/php-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings)

Comment: You have 'convert the timestamp', I think you mean 'formatted date/time string' instead of a 'timestamp'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its just that PHP timezone isn't set. So you can do that in php.ini or declare it in your php file.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$DOA = strtotime($row->DOA);
```

See if that eliminates your error.

Comment: thats it. i just had to add this information. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$timestamp = '1334826954';
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
$dateTime->setTimestamp($timestamp);
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output

```
2012-04-19 11:15:54
```

Comment: I see you have changed the question. You are not looking for converting a timestamp to formatted date/time string, you meant the other way around.