# "date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings..."

Tags: php, timezone

I got this error when I requested to update the [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) version from 5.2.17 to PHP 5.3.21 on the server.

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Log.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 86</p>

</div>
Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead in /filelocation right here/system/libraries/Log.php on line 86

Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead in /filelocation right here/system/libraries/Log.php on line 99
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Log.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 99</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 590, accepted):

You probably need to put the timezone in a configuration line in your `php.ini` file. You should have a block like this in your php.ini file:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/New_York
```

If not, add it (replacing the timezone by yours). After configuring, make sure to restart httpd (`service httpd restart`).

Here is the [list of supported timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: to be clear, after making this change, be sure to sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: This solved it for me when other solutions did not. I only received this error when I used date functions on the same page as integration with Amazon SES. Maybe that will help someone else.

Comment: @DOOManiac +1 same here

Comment: @CtrlX: I retract my comment; it was user error on my part (I was editing the wrong copy of php.ini)

Comment: If you are using PHP CLI (php -r or php -a) within your client terminal, you need to edit the CLI php.ini file, not apache2. YourC CLI php.ini file can usually be found at /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Comment: If you are using php-fpm - it's also need to be restarted: sudo service php-fpm restart

Comment: Like the first comment about Apache you must also restart IIS for this to take effect on Windows/IIS.

Comment: This solve my problem! Just an info for the non-experts like me, in order to find the `php.ini` used by apache, just execute the following command `php -i | grep php.ini`.

Comment: @JoëlSalamin, You could have just done `php --ini`. It will also give you additional information regarding potential errors.

Comment: If I use this solution. The result is 500 internal server errror.

Comment: @Shehbaz Ali : Did you wrote correctly the timezone name. If not, apache won't be able to start

Comment: I wrote it and restart the server from the service componenet in window 10. but, then it was giving 500 server error.

Comment: the same thing is working in my LAMP. On the window, I installed apache, PHP, MySQL from .msi file and configure them manually. the same code is not working.

Comment: @ShehbazAli : You should look into your apache error log to find out why you have that HTTP 500 error

Comment: This answer works if your server and account is setup to let you use a php.ini file. However, it did not work for me at first because the php.ini file was not recursive (did not apply to subfolders). So I also had to edit my .htaccess file and add this line: suphp_configpath /home/your_name/public_html - where your_name is your account name

Answer (score 213):

If you cannot modify your php.ini configuration, you could as well use the following snippet at the beginning of your code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');//or change to whatever timezone you want
```

The list of timezones can be found at http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php.

Comment: For some reason setting date.timezone = America/New_York in my php.ini and restart apache did not stop this error message when running a script using swiftmailer.  I ended up also having to add date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); at top of script as suggested.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried your solution. Now, error is 500 internal server error. I am using apache 2.x and codeigniter .

Comment: @ShehbazAli You must have done something wrong. In which of your scripts did your add the snippet?

Comment: the same code is working on the production. There is no error. I have installed the apache, php and MySQL manually on window 10. PHP, MySQL and Apache work. But, this project is giving error.

Answer (score 77):

Add the following in your `index.php` file. I first came across this when I moved my application from my [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) server to Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4...

I would advise you do it in your `index.php` file instead of the `php.ini` file.

```
if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
{
    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
}
```

Comment: excellent solution for when you don't necessarily have full system access, guess this one is for people with limited access or need a more robust solution, and combining this with editing the php.ini if you can

Answer (score 18):

```
<? print(gmdate("Y")); ?>
```

instead of

```
<? print(date("Y")); ?>
```

worked for me (shows current year and no more shows the error message).
(Thanks to Chris above)

Answer (score 16):

If these are not your options

- Modifying `php.ini`.
- Adding `date_default_timezone` call.

Instead of `date` you could use `gmdate`.

I have used `gmdate( "Y" )` when I needed a year for a copyright snipplet.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using CodeIgniter and can't change php.ini, I added the following to the beginning of index.php:

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
```

Comment: It works for me, thanks Jose for your help. 
Best Regards,
Sarim Ghani
http://www.i-splendid.com

Comment: This works on native php http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php. TY, you put me on the right track. In relation see timezone list for the function here http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 14):

I always keep this line inside codeigniter's root `index.php`.So that my code works at any server

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
```

[List of Supported Timezones here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 11):

@Justis pointed me to the right direction, but his code did not work for me. This did:

```
// set the default timezone if not set at php.ini
if (!date_default_timezone_get('date.timezone')) {
    // insert here the default timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
}
```

Documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

This solution is not only for those who does not have full system access. It is necessary for any script when you provide it to anyone else but you. You never know on what server the script will run when you distribute it to someone else.

Answer (score 5):

I had to put it in double quotes.

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles"); // default time zone
```

Comment: Still no workie (in Mac OSX), so I eventually broke down and added `/etc/php.ini: date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles`

Answer (score 5):

This issue has been bugging me for SOME time as im trying to inject a "createbucket.php" script into composer and i keep being told my time-zone is incorrect.

In the end the only thing that fixed the issue was to:
`$ sudo nano /etc/php.ini`

Search for **timezone**

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone
date.timezone = UTC
```

Ensure you remove the `;`

Then finally

```
$ sudo service httpd restart
```

And you'll be good to go :)

Answer (score 4):

You can set the timezone in your `.htaccess` file

```
php_value date.timezone UTC
```

Comment: This should work in the case php.ini still returns the warning despite having it set (php 5.4.*). Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to setting the date.timezone=   as mentioned in several answers,
I found an error in the php.ini file that was keeping it from getting to the date.timezone.
The way I found it was by running php from the command line in a terminal.
this caused an error to be reported at line 114.  In my case I had uncommented a setting for displaying errors that had '|'  between 2 values.  It did not like it.
I removed one of the values and the |  and everything was good after that

Answer (score 2):

```
<? date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul'); ?>
```

For php (or your location).

Answer (score 1):

A simple method for two time zone.

```
<?php 
$date = new DateTime("2012-07-05 16:43:21", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris')); 

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); 

echo date("Y-m-d h:iA", $date->format('U')); 

// 2012-07-05 10:43AM 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For docker user:
Create a local timezone.ini file in your project, set up the config in docker-compose.yml,

```
    volumes:
        - "./docker/config/timezone.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/timezone.ini"
```

timezone.ini

```
    date.timezone=Australia/Sydney
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution whilst your rectify the incompatibilities, is to disable error reporting in your `index.php` file:

Insert the line below into your **index.php** below `define( ‘_JEXEC’, 1 );`

```
error_reporting( E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR |
E_COMPILE_WARNING );
```

Answer (score 0):

I am hosting my EC2 and S3 bucket in us-west-2 (Oregon) region. When I was calling `$s3client->listBuckets()` to list existing buckets in my php, I was getting exception - `"Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings...".` 
I made below changes to make it work. Sharing these details in case someone is facing similar issue and any of above answers have not helped.

1. Based on documentation @ AWS  [Configuring Network Time Protocol (NTP)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html#configure_ntp), I confirmed ntpd service status is fine by running `ntpstat` command. If you get error, this link helps you to know what is going wrong.
2. Opened /etc/php.ini file (some may have it in different path based on version of php installed) and found that `date.timezone` was not set to any value and also it was commented by default. I un-commented by removing ';' before this line and set its value to `"UTC"` and saved the file.
3. Restarted http and ntp daemons using `sudo service httpd restart` and `sudo service ntpd restart` commands.

After this I am able to list buckets successfully without any exception. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Plesk, try it, First, Open PHP Settings, at the bottom of page, change date.timezone from DEFAULT to UTC.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this error running php-fpm in a chroot jail.  I tried creating etc/php.ini and /usr/share/zoneinfo in the chroot directory, but it just didn't work.  I even tried strace-ing the php-fpm daemons to see what file they were missing - nothing jumped out.

So in case Google brings you here because you get this error when using php-fpm configured for chroot, you can probably fix it by adding this line to `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` in the ENV section:

```
env[TZ] = America/New_York
```

A php-fpm restart is normally required for it to take effect.  Hope this helps somebody out there.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, I have PHP configured to use PHP-FPM (FastCGI Process Manager). When executing `phpinfo()` from CLI I saw correct timezone that I had set in the php.ini, however it was still incorrect in the browser and causing my code to fail. I simply needed to restart the `php-fpm` service on the server.

```
service rh-php56-php-fpm restart
```

You may also need to restart the `httpd` service if you edited the `php.ini`

```
service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16765214/4307527) above from [CtrlX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2138928/ctrlx) is the correct answer, but it may not work completely.
I added this line to my **php.ini** file:

```
date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"
```

but it did not remove the PHP error for all my files because some of my PHP scripts are in subfolders. So I had to edit **.htaccess** file to setup php.ini to be used recursively (in subfolders):

```
suphp_configpath /home/account_name/public_html
```

where account_name is your cpanel account name and public_html is the folder your php.ini file is in.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the file `php.ini`, create or edit a `.htaccess` file in the root of your domain or sub and add this (generated by cpanel):

```
<IfModule mime_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule php5_module>
php_value date.timezone "America/New_York"
</IfModule>

<IfModule lsapi_module>
php_value date.timezone "America/New_York"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please try not to use capital words in case that normal casing convention can express what you want to say.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for the resolve this

First, change into the php.ini file and put default timezone

```
date.timezone = "America/New_York"
```

Once, you have set the timezone in **php.ini** restart the server

Secondly, Change the run time
assign time zone based on your need

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done or created this in the .htaccess file:

```
php_value date.timezone Asia/Jakarta
```

But it doesn't work.
Then I tried to upgrade the php version from 5 to 7. And it solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

In your connection page put a code like  this `date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Johannesburg");` based on your current location.