# echo (new DateTime())->getTimestamp(); ... anonymous object not suported?

Tags: php, datetime, anonymous-objects

There is probably no way to do work with anonymous objects?

I want to do short thinks like this:

```
echo (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
```

In javascript we could shortly use:

```
alert( (new Date()).getTime() );
```

Is there any shorter way which can be used in php?

Without creating a function?

Dont wanna use a exta funktion .. for eg:

```
function timestamp() {
    $dt = new DateTime();
    return $dt->getTimestamp();
}
```

BTW: useful links: https://www.google.de/search?q=php+creating+anonymous+object
BTW2: this works:

```
$obj = (object) array('foo' => 'bar', 'property' => 'value');
echo $obj->foo;
```

Thanks all ! for your nice fast answers.

BTW3 (update from 13-11-22_16-12):

I found something useful also:

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
echo @date('H:i:s');
```

Comment: [Yes, you can.](http://3v4l.org/0FAFK)

Comment: @sl5net: if you wish to comment on answer, use comments, don't edit answers like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3418460). Btw: don't use `@` infront of date_create() call, no need for that ([demo](http://3v4l.org/EK15B)).

Comment: isn't simple time() the shortest way? http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shorter than:

```
echo (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
// or
echo (new DateTime)->getTimestamp();
# available in PHP >= 5.4.0
```

would be to use procedural style (or mix between object and procedural):

```
echo date_create()->getTimestamp();
# available in PHP >= 5.3.0

echo date_create()->format('U');
# available in PHP >= 5.2.0
```

or:

```
echo time();
```

Comment: procedural: `echo date_timestamp_get(date_create());`

Comment: @redreggae: let's say **mix** between object and procedural style then ;)

Answer (score 1):

Also, if [default timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) is not set, add the following at in the top of your adhoc script otherwise set default timezone in [php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16765214/4749156) for global settings.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney'); // set it your timezone
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is supported since PHP 5.4. In older versions you'll indeed have to assign the object to an intermediate variable.

Answer (score -1):

As of PHP 5.4, you can write

```
echo (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Wasn't me but your code won't work. You have to wrap it in brackets like the OP did in their question.

Comment: Gnah. Right you are. Thanks.