# PHP: How to sync data between s3 buckets using php code without using the CLI .?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, synchronization

I can't seem to find sync and copy options in the php sdk for amazon-s3. Currently I am using aws s3 cp/sync CLI command from within PHP code to achieve this which doesn't seem very neat to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of two features in the PHP SDK.

First, checkout the `S3Client::uploadDirectory()` method (see [user guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html#uploading-a-directory-to-a-bucket)). You can upload a while directory's contents like this:

```
$s3Client->uploadDirectory('/local/directory', 'your-bucket-name');
```

If you combine this with the [S3 Stream Wrapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html), then instead of using a local directory as the source, you can specify a bucket.

```
$s3Client->registerStreamWrapper();
$s3Client->uploadDirectory('s3://your-other-bucket-name', 'your-bucket-name');
```

This is pretty powerful, because you can even do something across regions if you use a differently configured `S3Client` object for the Stream Wrapper than the one doing the `uploadDirectory()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy. It works like a charm. The only issue it caused was the fatal error because of missing timezone information from php.ini file. Adding the timezone information made it work. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765158/date-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings-in-codeigniter

One question though. Is it as efficient as CLI tool ?

Comment: Not sure. I guess you'd have to test that out on your own.

Comment: I used the aws cli client to try to copy over 500k objects. It missed a lot of objects and also did not copy ACL permissions. Trying the above method now will report back.

Comment: @JeremyLindblom, I am getting error while using uploadDirectory() with registerStreamWrapper(). Please review my code below -

$s3 = new S3Client(['credentials' => $credentials,
        'version' => 'latest','region'  => $region,'debug'   => false
    ]);

$s3->registerStreamWrapper();

$result = $s3->uploadDirectory("s3://{$source_bucket}/{$key}",$target_bucket);

Comment: One major thing to be aware of though, in `v3` of the PHP SDK `S3Client::uploadDirectory()` does not intelligently sync, it uploads everything again. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960048/is-sync-in-amazon-s3-php-sdk-api-really-a-sync-operation/.