# PHP warning when I use the date function

Tags: php

I have this line in my PHP code to generate a guid based on date, member id and comment:

```
$md5c = md5($member_id.$comment.$topic_id.$plan_id.date("Y-m-d") );
```

Recently it started giving warning messages like this:

```
Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.
```

Would anyone know how to change that code so that this warning is not generated?

Thanks!

Comment: Open your `PHP.ini` and write a new value for the `date.timezone` setting as mentioned by in the Answer by @Saman Gholami

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to put the timezone in a configuration line in your php.ini file. You should have a block like this in your php.ini file:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/New_York
```

If not, add it (replacing the timezone by yours). After configuring, make sure to restart httpd (service httpd restart).

Here is the [list of supported timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).
The reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765158/date-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings-in-codeigniter).

Comment: I already have a setting like this in my php.ini file: date.timezone = "US/Eastern" ....is that not enough?

Comment: and do I need the quotes like I currently have? In your example there are no quotes.