# PHP: Convert YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY?

Tags: php

Yes, I know there are a lots of other topics about it, but my problem is here:

I only can use

```
date_format(new DateTime($ymd_date_from_db), “d.m.Y H:i:s“
```

when I set the timezone in my php.  but I dont want to set it, because there is no need for timezone, because the timestamp value is already in $ymd_date_from_db - so i dont want to set timezone in php in addition to that.  also date(....) does not work:

"It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings "

- same problem , it wants me to set timezone in php.

Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `strtotime()`:

```
date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `format` method

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime($ymd_date_from_db);
    echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
?>
```

Comment: it fgives me same error: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings

Comment: Do you have access to the apache config file? If so, use the steps outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16765214/1572528

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime::format()` e.g:

```
$DateTimeObj->format('your format')
```

Comment: same error: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings