# How do I set time zone in codeigniter config files?

Tags: php, codeigniter, timezone

Currently I am using:

```
SetEnv TZ America/Los_Angeles
```

in htaccess.

Is there a way to define the timezone in the codeignitor config files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765158/date-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings-in-codeigniter/27879205#27879205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write in your `index.php` codeignator file:

```
if (function_exists("date_default_timezone_set"))
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
```