# How to change codeigniter timezone inside model

Tags: php, codeigniter

Where I have to change the time-zone, if I want to to have the timezone of the current user, at the point of inserting any data?

I have tried the following code inside my model, but it is not working:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Nicosia');
$this->db->set('TIME', 'NOW()', FALSE);
$this->db->insert('LOGS', $data3);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765158/date-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings-in-codeigniter/27879205#27879205

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19069310/2441442

Comment: I have confused! How to find my codeigniter's root index.php? In routes.php I have define as $route['default_controller'] = "main/login";

Comment: I dont use index.php files. I use index methods inside controllers...