# "It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings" after setting it

Tags: php, timezone

At the beginning of my configuration file I have:

```
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    echo "Set default timezone: " . date_default_timezone_get() . "\n";
   ...
```

I execute PHP script via CLI and the output looks like this:

> Set default timezone: America/Los_Angeles
>
> PHP Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in

Why am I receiving the message "It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings" even after setting the timezone?

------ UPDATE ---------

Turns out this is a threading problem, so need to set to php.ini to solve it.

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/config.php';

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

echo "Timezone: " . date_default_timezone_get() . "\n";

function threadTest() {
    echo "Thread Timezone: " . date_default_timezone_get() . "\n";
}

$thread = new Thread_Async();
$thread->call('threadTest');
```

Results:

> Timezone: America/Los_Angeles
>
> PHP Warning:  date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on
>   the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
>   date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In
>   case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to
>   select your timezone. in /pvolf/wwwdev/app/test.php on line 10
>
> Thread Timezone: UTC

Comment: I tested your code on CLI and browser and I cannot reproduce the error. Are you sure you've saved the file already ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765158/date-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings-in-codeigniter)

Comment: i think this is happening inside a `Thread_Async` object, could that be the cause? Perhaps timezone settings dont get copied over when you make a new thread?

Comment: works 100% here on the 3 servers i have access to

Comment: i realized it was a problem with threading, thanks for your inputs though

Answer (score 0):

Check your ini that's used for command line. I bet it has no timezone set. Try running command line with `-d date.timezone=UTC` eg:

```
php -d date.timezone=UTC foo.php
```

Comment: shouldn't matter,  date_default_timezone_set overrides the ini setting

Comment: i figured out the problem, timezone settings dont get passed to Thread_Async