# set default date and time zone for date input

Tags: php, jquery, date

I have two inputs for pick up date and return date.I want to add today's date to be default value for pick up date and in case user changes the date, the value for return date should change to one day ahead to pick up date.any help will be appreciated.
i already used  time(), it gives me warning metioned in comments belows.

`<input type="date" name="pickupdate" class="form-control user-success" id="pickupdate" placeholder="MM/DD/YY">
<input type="date" name="returndate" class="form-control user-success" id="RETURNDATE" placeholder="MM/DD/YY">`

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Input Type Date -- Default Value to Today?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/html5-input-type-date-default-value-to-today)

Comment: this is not exact duplicate but i dont found my answer there for return date .and setting time zone .kindly remove the duplicate and let me get answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

use

Add time zone top of the php page

```
 date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Current date:`<?php echo date("Y/m/d")?>`

Tomorrow :`<?php echo date("Y/m/d", time()+86400)?>`

```
   <input type="text" name="pickupdate" class="form-control user-success" id="pickupdate" placeholder="MM/DD/YY" value="<?php echo date("Y/m/d")?>">

<input type="text" name="returndate" class="form-control user-success" id="RETURNDATE" value="<?php echo date("Y/m/d", time()+86400)?>">
```

Comment: what about return date ? if pick up date is 24 return should be 25

Comment: check it and let me know

Comment: thanks alot and can you help me about this warning  about time zone i have no idea about that 
**Warning: date_create(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone**

Comment: refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765158/date-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings

Comment: if you want answer about your new issue post new question

Comment: did you set timezone in your php file or php.ini?

Comment: I didnt added it. plz let me know where to add it in server . In cpanel i have public html folder where i add my files?

Comment: which cpanel are you using?

Comment: its linux based i dont know much information about that. its first time  i am getting this . i think there is some problem with date()

Comment: sir its working but i have to use it in every page then? i guess its already somewhere in php.ini , is there a way to set it once .

Comment: [Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/New_York

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765158/date-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-phpini-file

Comment: check your php.ini file or add code in header file or database config file

Comment: who told you this is duplicate?

Comment: please remove "remove this -1 plz :) its not duplicate"