# How to concatenate multiple strings in php?

Tags: php, string, string-concatenation

I want to concatenate 3 strings. For first string I am splitting it to get first 4 letters. Another is `user_name` and the last is `date_of_application`.

we use `.`(dot operator) in PHP. But as I am doing in this, In result first two strings are concatenated well but third i.e. `date_of_application`, only first 2 or 4 letters are getting concatenated not the whole string.

```
$this-> member_id = mb_substr($this->country, 0, 4) . $this->user_name . $this->date_of_application;
```

**Input:**

28/08/2016,28082016

**results:**

Indisid128/0, Indisiddhi28

EDIT:

I want to get the digits from date.Input date can be in any format. For example- if input date is 28 Aug 2016. The output should be concatenated string _ 28082016. How can I get this?

What's going wrong?

Comment: Both results seems to have a length of 12 characters. Is there variable `member_id` somehow limited to 12 characters?

Comment: yes that's right the limit was 12. @mnille

Comment: Waht is `$this->date_of_application`?

Comment: So this question is answered then? The limit being 12 was the problem? Because there's no reproducible problem here at all.

Comment: ??? 8 up votes for this question ???

Comment: Why 8 up votes? Does not even contain proper example input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not concatenate `date` with `string` with your existing format. You need to convert it (slashes are removed).

Write `date('Y_m_d-H-i-s', strtotime($this->date_of_application));`

Write your code as below:

```
$country = mb_substr($this->country, 0, 4);
$username = $this->user_name;
$converted_date = date('Y_m_d-H-i-s', strtotime($this->date_of_application));
$this->member_id = $country . $username . $converted_date;
```

Comment: I am getting this message when I run the code. Its getting concatenated well though.  It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. @RaviHirani

Comment: @Sid Please check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765158/date-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings

Comment: What if input date is in different format? like 28-08-2016 or 28 Aug 2016? @RaviHirani

Comment: it's showing this format - 1970_01_01-00-00-00 , I only want the digits from date , I want to save date in 8 digits. Like if input is 28 aug 2016 the output should be concatenated string + 28082016. @RaviHirani

Comment: I tried changing the timezone but it dose not give date as desired. input is- 28/08/2016 , output is - 1970_01_01-04-00-00 . @RaviHirani

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_of_application = date('m/d/Y');
$user_name = 'TestUser';
$country = 'India';
echo $member_id = mb_substr($country, 0, 4) . $user_name . $date_of_application;
```

I try this and it's working fine

Comment: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. @Vinod Kumar

Comment: What if input date is in different format? like 28-08-2016 or 28 Aug 2016? @Vinod Kumar

Comment: if format is 28-08-2012 than it will give  the result "IndiTestUser08-29-2016" @ Sid
Where are you using this.. in any framework ?

Comment: I only want to save the 8 digits of date. @Vinod Kumar

Answer (score -2):

Consider casting the value of $this->date_of_application to `string`, like:

```
$this->member_id = mb_substr($this->country, 0, 4) . $this->user_name . (String)$this->date_of_application;
```

Alternatively, in scenarios where you want to be using variable values within strings, you could use interpolation instead of concatenation, like:

```
$this->member_id = mb_substr($this->country, 0, 4) . "{$this->user_name}{$this->date_of_application}";
```

Comment: The value will automatically be cast to a string when used with the *string concatenation operator*…

Comment: Any reference you can provide for that?

Comment: [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) doesn't seem to make any explicit mention of it, but it's easy to test experimentally: `"" . []` → "Array", which is the expected result of an array-to-string cast.

Comment: I guess you're right. I've always used casting in function calls to ensure that parameters passed to the function are of the same types that the function argument lists expect. I realize this is superfluous for string concatenation.