# how do i sort out this warning on my php mail page

Tags: php, function, email, time, fixed

i tried sending email using my php mail function but i get this warning during process

Warning: mail(): It is not safe to rely on the system's
timezone settings. You are
*required* to use the
date.timezone setting or the
date_default_timezone_set()
function. In case you used any of those methods and you are
still getting this warning, you
most likely misspelled the
timezone identifier. We
selected the timezone 'UTC' for
now, but please set date.timezone to select your
timezone. in

my problem is how do i fixed time for my php mail function to read out this warning on my php mail page
this my code:

```
  $to      = xvy@gmail.com        $message = yes go email;
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $time = date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');
    $headers = 'From: stringemail@gm.Com';

    $go = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if ($go)
    {
        echo 'good result';
    }
```

Big thank in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765158/date-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the timezone for the whole PHP environment.

You can do it within your script with  PHP function [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) with the timezone [List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php):

```
 <?php 
 date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');
 // rest of your script goes here...
```