# Can you someone help me fix my Contact Form PHP code?

Tags: php, email, syntax, contact-form

I have coded a contact form in PHP and have an error please can you help me?

php Form code:

```
<form class="contact-form" action="submit.php" method="post"> 
              <div class="row">
                  <!--Name-->
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input name="name" class="form-inp" type="text" placeholder="Name">
                  </div>
                  <!--Email-->
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input name="email" class="form-inp" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-12">
                      <!--Message-->
                      <textarea name="message" placeholder="How can I help you?" rows="7"></textarea>
                      <button name="submit" class="site-btn top_45 pull-right" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </form>
```

submit.php code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$mailTo = "info@xxxx.com";
$headers = "From: ".$email;
$txt = "You have received an email from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;

mail($mailTo, $email, $message);
header("Location: index.php?mailsend");
}
```

> Warning: Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in
>   /home/brukitup/public_html/submit.php on line 2
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in
>   /home/brukitup/public_html/submit.php on line 2

Answer (score -2):

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/brukitup/public_html/submit.php on line 2

This error is because you're missing a `)` in

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']){
                          ^^
```

As for your other warning, it's likely due to php settings. In your `php.ini`, set this

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = <whatever timezone you want to use>
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16765214/4516316))